# Get element of td on same level (by it's class)

Tags: jquery, html, children

I've got a table, each row containing 3 `<td>`. Now, I assigned a class-name to the `<tr>`, and another one to the first `<td>` of said `<tr>`. I created a click event for the whole `<tr>`, which then should get the html value of the first `<td>` (that one with the class name). I used children, as it seems does select the right `<td>`, but I can't figure out how to read it's html value (innerHTML).

HTML:

```
<tr class="dataset">
    <td class="changeid">2</td>
    <td>Someone's name</td>
    <td>Some other info</td>
</tr>
```

JS:

```
$(".dataset").click(function() {
    temp = $(this).children(".changeid"); // It only returns 1 result

    // How to get it's HTML value?
}
```

I don't know if this was the best approach to solve it, it would have been easier for me if I could have used unique id's for all rows, but unfortunately the HTML is generated, and doesn't allow giving different id's to each `<tr>`.

Comment: `$(this).children(".changeid").html()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the element's `innerHTML`, use jQuery's [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) method.

```
$(".dataset").click(function() {
    var temp = $(this).children(".changeid").html();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You dont even need the class to identify the first element:

```
$(".dataset").click(function() {
 var temp = $(this).children(":first").html();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".dataset").click(function() {
   var id = $(this).find("td").eq(0).html();
   var name = $(this).find("td").eq(1).html();
   var info = $(this).find("td").eq(2).html();
}
```